# R, arima() with include.mean=TRUE, still has no mean reported

Tags: r, time-series

I have a regression with ARMA errors, which I am fitting with `arima()`. I know that the ARMA model is being fit on these residuals from the regression. My problem is that when I use `include.mean=TRUE` the output does not return any estimate of the mean (of the residuals, which yes, I know is always zero). The documentation says that ARMA model will include a mean if this option is set to `TRUE`.

I do see an intercept reported, which is the intercept from the regression of y on x, not the intercept from the ARMA model on the residuals.

How do I get the `include.mean` argument to work? Is there any other way to get the intercept from the ARMA model on residuals? Is R just censoring this because residuals are always mean zero (if intercept is in regression)?

MWE is below, thanks in advance.

`set.seed(123)
y = as.xts(ts(rnorm(20)+3, start=c(1980,1), freq=12))
x = as.xts(ts(rnorm(20)+5, start=c(1980,1), freq=12))`

`fit1 = arima(y, xreg=as.data.frame(x), order=c(1,0,0), include.mean=TRUE)
fit1 # intercept shown is from the regression, 3-(-.0935)*(5), not for the residual ARMA model`

Comment: What do you want? A mean for the fitted values? mean(fitted(fit1)) Or a mean for the residuals? mean(residuals(fit1))

Comment: I think you have answered your question. Don't know how you can estimate 2 intercepts (for xreg and for resid) simultaneously. Furthermore, what does it mean to have an intercept for resid?

Comment: @nsw, I would like the intercept parameter, or the mean, to be estimated in my ARMA models.

Comment: @qoheleth, intercept for ARMA residuals model means the same as any intercept any other time. It should just have the value zero, doesn't mean there is anything different in estimating it.

Comment: then what nsw suggested will do I suppose. `mean(residuals(fit1))`

Comment: @qoheleth, it seems if that is the only way then the `include.mean=TRUE` option is not working (or at least, not working according to the documentation) in this case.

Comment: mmm.... still not sure why you say it is not working, perhaps it is difference in interpretation. But my reading of it is that the 'mean' in the 'include.mean' with xreg not null, refers to the mean column in xreg. i.e. intercept for the main effect. (which is really the only sensible interpretation I think) So if you do include.mean=FALSE, the intercept term in xreg is removed.